# Populate a simple TableColumn in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am experimenting with displaying an ArrayList of strings in a javaFX tablecolumn. I have read many examples which go into details about displaying and dynamically modifying custom classes etc, but I just want to see a fundamental implementation of a column displaying arraylist data.
I have tried various methods, involving using an ObservableList, but my interest is more basic than that.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here is my code: 
Main:

```
package testCram;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainWindow.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Controller:

```
package testCram;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import java.util.*;

public class Controller {
//instances of all controls

@FXML
public TableView<String> table;
@FXML
public TableColumn<String , String> column1;

public void setData(){

    Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("String1");
    list.add("String2");
    list.add("String3");
    list.add("String4");
    list.add("String5");
    list.add("String6");

    //I understand that you need to use 'setCellValueFactory' but I don't see what is needed to extract the values from list.
    column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-                           Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="718.0" prefWidth="569.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testCram.Controller">
 <columnConstraints>
     <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />

 </columnConstraints>
 <rowConstraints>
 <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />

</rowConstraints>
<children>
<Pane prefHeight="718.0" prefWidth="596.0">
<children>
<TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="399.0">
<columns>
<TableColumn fx:id="column1" prefWidth="100.0" text="String" />
</columns>
</TableView>
</children></Pane>
</children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: A `TableColumn` must have a non-null [cellValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty) property.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this further , and I will post my own answer:

In order for the column to disaply data, you must instruct the table to populate the data:
Add the line:
table.getItems().addAll(list);

under

column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));

I hope this helps someone else who gets stuck.

Comment: It's only counter-intuitive, if you've got the wrong assumption about what `TableColumn` is responsible for. It tells `TableView` how to convert the row item to an `ObservableValue` that contains the data to display via its `cellValueFactory`.

Comment: disagreed, there's nothing non-intuitive: the table contains a list of data objects, each column presents one of the properties of that data object. So there are two thingies to do: a) tell the table which list of data to contain (via setItems/addItem) and b) tell the column which property to present (via cellValueFactory). Studying an arbitrary basic tutorial on fx might have helped - just saying ;)